# MathML, Latex or similar for web-based WYSIWYG editor

Tags: latex, wysiwyg, mathml

I am looking for a web-based WYSIWYG (or WYSIWYM) editor like TinyMCE or WMD Editor (used to write this question) that supports users to write mathematical formulas. I have looked at LaTeX a little bit but it has a learning curve and I am not sure if support for MathML is extensive. Ideally I would also like to avoid having to rewrite an editor and would rather just pick one off the shelf.

Would like to know if any of you have dealt with a similar situation and what solution you adopted/built.

Comment: Question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433540/embeddable-wysiwyg-equation-editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.dessci.com/en/ has the software to do exactly what you want.

Comment: It's a good software, unfortunately it's not web based

Comment: Yes it is, look at http://www.dessci.com/en/products/webeq/.

Comment: "WebEQ Developers Suite Reaches End of Life"

Comment: It's been renamed/repackaged as MathFlow apparently:  http://www.dessci.com/en/products/mathflow/

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for something similar and came across this question. Then I was excited to find [Mathquill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_editor), via the [Wikipedia page on formula editors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_editor).

I've used a bunch of different formula editors, from MS Equation Editor to Google Docs' to LyX, and this is probably the most usable/fluid of all of them for simply banging out formulas. And it's web-based and GPL. This thing is much nicer than Google Docs' formula editor, at least.

Still leaves plenty of things to be desired, e.g. so far I've found: bolding, entering things like bra-kets, \hat, undo/redo history, mouse drag selection, etc. But I'm impressed by what's already in there. Anyway, it's just a few Javascript files, and [on github](https://github.com/mathquill/mathquill).

Comment: The newer "master" version of the repo is here: https://github.com/mathquill/mathquill

Answer (score 2):

I used [texvc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texvc) in a project a while back (what wikipedea uses) and it was reasonable, but it isn't really WYSIWYG.  On the other hand, I prefer that since in many cases it's easier to specify what you mean than draw it.

Answer (score 1):

see here DragMath

http://www.dragmath.bham.ac.uk/index.html

which is already used by Moodle and other sites.

And its Open Source

Comment: All you have to do to make this work is convince the entire planet to install Java on their computers.

Answer (score 0):

[WIRIS](http://www.wiris.com/en) would be another Javascript based visual math editor (commercial license required for some applications).